# Understanding tensor ranks and behaviour

Tags: python, tensorflow, rank, tensor

I am starting out with tensorflow and I have a huge problem when it comes to the ranks of tensors and how they interact with each other.

I have the following code with me:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.constant([0.2,0.6]))  
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)  
y =  w * x
```

As you can see, it is an incredibly simple setup.
However, when I execute the `print w` the output is `Tensor("Variable_13/read:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)`.
What is the meaning of `shape(2,)`? What does the comma indicate?

Further, here are the other sore points after `sess = tf.Session()` and initialising the variables:

```
print(sess.run(y,{x:[1,2]}))
```

[ 0.2         1.20000005]

```
print(sess.run(y,{x:[1]}))
```

[ 0.2         0.60000002]

```
print(sess.run(y,{x:[[1],[2]]}))
```

[[ 0.2         0.60000002]
    [ 0.40000001  1.20000005]]

Why am I getting such a variety of behaviour? How is tensorflow determining a single data point? I realise now that specifying shape while declaring the placeholder is probably better than getting myself stuck like this.
I understand the last two cases as they were taught in class, but I am at a loss to explain the behaviour of the first case.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is a simple one. `shape=(2,)` refers to the dimensions of `w`. In `numpy`, shape is always represented by a tuple of integers, like this:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(50)
>>> x.shape
(50,)
```

This is a 1D array, and only one integer is specified in the `shape`. Now,...

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(50, 50)
>>> x.shape
(50, 50)
```

This is a 2D array. As you can see, `shape` specifies the size of `x` along 2 dimensions.

---

To answer your second question, `x` is a placeholder, meaning it can take up any value you give it. That is precisely what the following lines do: `{x:[1,2]}`, `{x:[1]}` and `{x:[[1],[2]]}`

In the first case, x is assigned a 1D array of 2 elements `[1, 2]`. In the second case, a 1D array with 1 element `[1]` and so on.

Now, the operation `w * x` above specifies that `w` should be multiplied with `x`. So, when doing `sess.run(y,{x:[1,2]})`, `w` is multiplied by `x` with the values passed to it. And the output you see changes depending on the value you pass to `x`.

In the first case, `[0.2, 0.6] * [1, 2]` just multiplies each element at their corresponding indices and the result is `[0.2 * 1, 0.6 * 2]`.

The second case does something similar.

In the third case, we have x with dimensions (2, 1). So each row of `x` is in turn multiplied with `w` to get a separate row, giving `[[ 0.2, 0.60000002], [ 0.40000001, 1.20000005]]` as your output.

Answer (score 1):

#### First question

`shape(2,)` indicates the shape of the tensor. In particular, the comma at the end indicates that the tensor is tuple.

You can check this simply running:

```
type((2))
```

that returns `int`, whilst

```
type((2,))
```

returns `tuple`.

#### Second question

You just discovered the **broadcasting**.

In short, in the first case, you're multiplying singularly each element of the 2 input tensors.

In the second case, you're multiplying a tensor for a scalar.

In the third case, instead, you're multiplying each element of `w` for each element of `x`. This because x has shape `(something, 1)`. The `1` in the last dimension "trigger" a broacasting rule that makes the operation to behave in such way.

You should read the brodacasting rules here for a better understanding: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules